# data is not getting saved

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-O72COGQ;Initial Catalog=ClinicManagementtest;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO  Patient_Details VALUES(@Id, @Name, @Age, @Contact No, @Address", con);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", textBox1.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox2.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact No", textBox3.Text);

            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textBox5.Text);
            int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(o + ":Record has been inserted");
            con.Close();

        }
```

[image]

Comment: you missed the parenthesis in end of the insert command.

Comment: Don't make your life harder. Do not use spaces in parameters names. And you have 6 fields, insert 5 parameter placeholders but add only 4 parameters. Did you get an exception?

Comment: I would argue not to use spaces in sql identifiers at all...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes that's absolutely true. Sometime I have seen the excuse that a space is required to show a better title in grid columns for the end user, but this is just an excuse because every grid control allows you to change the column headers text

Comment: @Steve i igree with you

Comment: Also, read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a lot of errors here.

- First, you have 6 fields in your table and, if you don't give a list
  of fields when you make an insert query, then you should add values
  for **all 6 fields**.
- Second you have 5 parameters placeholders but you add only 4
  parameters and this is another exception.
- Last but not least the syntax of the insert statement is formally
  wrong because there is no closing parenthesys

So, let's try to fix at the best of our knowledge

```
string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO  Patient_Details 
                         (ID, Name, Age, Gender, [Contact No], Address) 
                   VALUES(@Id,@Name,@Age,@Gender,@ContactNo,  @Address)"
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", textBox1.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox2.Text);

    // For the following two fields, add a value or remove 
    // the parameters and fix the query text above....
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", ????); 
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", ????);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", textBox3.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textBox5.Text);
    int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    MessageBox.Show(o + ":Record has been inserted");
}
```

Comment: Someone is finding fun in downvoting the answers here?

Answer (score -1):

Like Sankar Raj pointed out you missed the a `)` in the `Insert` query and a parameter `@Age` to add.Using space in parameter `@Contact No` is also not allowed.
You have used `using` for `SqlConnection`.I suggest you use the same for `SqlCommand` also, then you don't need to explicitly `Dispose` it. And again it seems you are not using `try catch` that's you were not able to identity the problem.

**SUGGESTED CODE**

```
try{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-O72COGQ;Initial Catalog=ClinicManagementtest;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO  Patient_Details VALUES(@Id, @Name, @Age,@Gender, @ContactNo, @Address)", con)){
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", textBox1.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox2.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", textBox3.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", textBox4.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", textBox5.Text);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textBox6.Text);
            int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(o + ":Record has been inserted");
        }
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Note: I've removed `con.Close()`. Since you are using `using` statement it will automatically `Close` & `Dispose` the  Connection and release the resources it uses.

Comment: May I know why the down vote? Care to give me a reason

Comment: I would say that your answer cannot work because the table has 6 fields and without giving the column names in the INSERT then you need to add all 6 fields values